# Update `valueSet` for a `customField` on Sales Force using the tooling API

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I am trying to update the picklist for a custom field on salesforce, using the [tooling](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_resource_examples.htm) API.

This is my payload:

```py
        payload = {
            "Metadata": {
                "valueSet": {
                    "valueSetDefinition": {
                        "value": [{'color': None, 'default': False, 'description': None, 'isActive': None, 'label': 'Agilysis'}],
                        "sorted": True,
                    },
                    "restricted": False,
                }
            },
        }
```

I am making the request using the python library [simple-salesforce](https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/)

```
response = sf.toolingexecute(self.SALES_FORCE_OBJECT_NAME + self.id, method='PATCH', data=payload)
```

This leads to the following errors message:

```
simple_salesforce.exceptions.SalesforceMalformedRequest: Malformed request https://canarytechnologies.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N5w00000ObMPzEAN. Response content: [{'message': 'At least one value is required to create this picklist.', 'errorCode': 'FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION', 'fields': []}]
```

I am unable to find the problem with my payload. I am using the API version 52.0.

Comment: Salesforce Stack Exchange may have more insight on this question.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing defining `fullName` for the value (only defining `label`) which is why it's throwing an error saying there's no values.

```
payload = {
            "Metadata": {
                "valueSet": {
                    "valueSetDefinition": {
                        "value": [{'color': None, 'default': False, 'description': None, 'isActive': None, 'label': 'Agilysis', 'fullName': 'Agilysis'}],
                        "sorted": True,
                    },
                    "restricted": False,
                }
            },
        }
```